# FakeRAID problems - Should be 21 Tib but only showing 3.83Tib

Tags: raid, dmraid

I have a ASrock 177 +7 extreme motherboard and four 8TB hard drives in a fake raid. I use this just for storage. I believe the RAID controller is Intel.

I also have a 512gb ssd that is used to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.10. My Win10 can see the RAID 5 with no problems. But in Gparted it shows the 512gb drive, and four 8tb drives and a RAID5 3.83 TiB "/dev/mapper/isw_bhabiaaeci_RAID5". I do not have the drives partitioned or formatted.

What am I doing wrong where it will only show 3.83 TiB instead of the 21.84 Tib volume.

Here is a screenshot of Gparted imgur.com/a/NN11M

Edit: I added 3 of the 4 drives to a RAID just to see what would happen and now the RAID volume is 2.55 Tib. I'm using 128kb blocks. I also changed the blocks from 128kb to 64kb and nothing changed.

Edit2: I added all 4 drives to a RAID 0 and now the volume is 5.11 Tib.

Edit3: I'm starting to wonder if ubuntu can't handle RAID properly like windows.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you looked for similar problems with fakeraid reporting incorrect size? I found this: http://askubuntu.com/q/113561/40581 I'd say you're doing nothing wrong except using dmraid. Oh and please use the edit function to add details to your question instead of just commenting on it.

Comment: Do I need to uninstall dmraid? I ran the command sudo dmraid -rE and it breaks down the raid but I created several other types of RAIDs and nothing is working.